# Ignore NaNs in mean and other stats functions using Armadillo

Tags: c++, armadillo

If a matrix contains `NaN` values, Armadillo will return `NaN` for stats performed on the columns/rows containing these `NaN`s. I.e. the following code

```
arma::mat A = {{1, 2, 3}, {6, 7, 8}, {4, 9, 10}};
A(1,1) = arma::datum::nan;
std::cout << A << "\n";
std::cout << arma::mean(A) << "\n" << arma::mean(A, 1);
```

will return

```
1.0000    2.0000    3.0000
6.0000       nan    8.0000
4.0000    9.0000   10.0000

3.6667      nan   7.0000

2.0000
   nan
7.6667
```

Is there an efficient way to ignore the `NaN` values much like MATLAB's `nanmean()` / `mean(-, 'omitnan')`?

The column-wise mean would then return 5.5, the row-wise mean 7 instead of `NaN`.

Comment: It's not quite the same. I don't want to replace, just ignore. I could use `find_finite()`, but I'd have to iterate through rows / columns, calculate the means, and aggregate.

Comment: Armadillo is open source so you can extend it with however efficient algorithms you want to.

Comment: You can, for the case you describe, use `A.elem( find_nonfinite(A) ).zeros();` or `A.replace(datum::nan, 0);`

Comment: @ClaesRolen thanks, but in this case it won't work: replacing `NaN`s with zeros will skew the means (the column's mean would be 11/3 rather than 11/2, etc.).